# Creating an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I've seen an arry list set up as follows

```
private ArrayList<Student> students; //instance variable

public CollegeCommunity()//constructor

{
    students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

And as follows

```
 ArrayList exampleArray = new ArrayList();
```

I understand why one has an instance variable/constructor and the other just is simply declared but I'm unsure as to why the first contains `<Student>` and the other has no `<...>`
What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

The difference lies in the language feature known as generics, which are explained in the Java Tutorials trail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

`exampleArray` is declared using the [*raw type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) of the generic class `ArrayList`...

> A *raw type* is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments.

Raw types have *no* generic type information, and thus are identical to uses of the class before generics were introduced.

On the other hand, `students` uses a generic [*parameterized type*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

> A *generic type* is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types.

[Generics are useful](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) in that they allow the compiler to have more type information and thus ease programming by allowing it to effectively infer types, which is used in enforcing **strong typing** and **eliminating casts**.

The raw `ArrayList` is **almost** equivalent to `ArrayList<Object>`. The difference is highlighted in *Effective Java*.

> Just what is the difference between the raw type `List` and the parameterized type `List<Object>`?
>
> Loosely speaking, the former has opted out generic type checking, while the latter explicitly told the compiler that it is capable of holding objects of any type. While you can pass a `List<String>` to a parameter of type `List`, you can't pass it to a parameter of type `List<Object>`. There are subtyping rules for generics, and `List<String>` is a subtype of the raw type `List`, but not of the parameterized type `List<Object>`.
>
> As a consequence, you lose type safety if you use raw type like List, but not if you use a parameterized type like `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

`students` is using what is called generics. Generics constrain the types that can be passed to the `ArrayList`. `exampleArray` does not specify a type.

Answer (score 0):

The first ArrayList declatation has the generic type defined whereas exampleArray has not. It is advisable where possible to use generics to avoid the need for casting:

E.g.

```
ArrayList<Student> students = ...;
Student student = students.get(0);
```

versus:

```
ArrayList exampleArray = ...;
Example example = (Example)exampleArray.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason there is the `<Students>` next to `ArrayList` is because you need to specify what type of `data` the `ArrayList` will be holding. in this case the person is telling java that he want an `ArrayList` that contains the data type of class `Students`

without doing this it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is just a hint to the compiler. The declaration `new ArrayList<Student>()`
enforces the fact that you are going to store just instances of `Student` class inside the specified collection. This allows Java to keep `strong type-safety` through generics.

At runtime **nothing** won't change since Java has [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure) but this strong constraint will help you: the compiler will raise errors whenever you will try to use the collection with a different time compared to the one you used to declared it. It's called [*parametric polymorphism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism).

The raw declaration `new ArrayList()` instead instantiates a list on which there is no assumption for the type of objects you are going to store inside it: this means that everything can be stored but you will need to cast back objects when retrieving them. In addition you won't have any type safety since at compile time the compiler wouldn't be able to check what you will try to insert inside the collection.